# WebSocket server c# receiving & identifying multiple messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, websocket, json.net

I have created an ASP.NET c# project, consists of a web form and a WebSocket handler. I would send some data in JSON format from the web form to the WebSocket handler.

The web form would have this code snippet:

```
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(amt));
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(name));
```

Under the WebSocket handler's OnMessage(string message) method, I would convert the data sent by the web form in JSON format to c# format. But, how does the OnMessage method in the WebSocket handler knows which data is "amt" and which data is "name"?

Comment: You serialized it with JSON so you should deserialize it with JSON too.

Comment: @a-ctor, how to deserialize it with JSON? Can you give me the sample code, please?